# How do I migrate "yarn run-script build" task from frontend-maven-plugin to gradle?

Tags: maven-plugin, yarnpkg, gradle-task, gradle-node-plugin

I use gradle-node-plugin instead of frontend-maven-plugin.
"yarn run-script build" task in maven is written such as following

```
<execution>
   <id>yarn run-script build</id>
   <goals>
      <goal>yarn</goal>
   </goals>
   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
   <configuration>
      <arguments>build</arguments>
      <environmentVariables>
         <buildDir>${project.build.directory}/classes/static</buildDir>
      </environmentVariables>
   </configuration>
</execution>
```

In gradle, I wrote yarnScriptBuild task

```
task yarnScriptBuild(type: YarnTask, dependsOn: yarnTest) {
    group 'Node'
    args = ['run', 'build']
}
```

If I did "./gradlew yarnScriptBuild" command,
I got the error "Output path MUST not be project root directory!"
Then I inserted `outputs.dir = ("$buildDir/classes")` to yarnScriptBuild,but it didn't work.
(I found the page "$buildDir means {root directory}/build" few days ago)
I got another error "No such property: dir for class: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskOutputs"

Does this mean that "dir" property isn't exist?
How should I do? What is missing?

If information lacks, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the `yarnWorkDir` and `nodeWorkDir` in `NodeExtension` :

```
NodeExtension node = project.extensions.getByType(NodeExtension.class)
node.with {
     nodeModulesDir = ${pathToDirWithNodeModulesDir}
     yarnWorkDir = ${pathToYarnJs}
}
```

also, you might want to fix your `outputs` path to this:

`outputs.dir = project.file("$buildDir/classes")`

or this:

`output.dir "$buildDir/classes"`